# How to encrypt config file in a Perl Dancer application?

Tags: perl, encryption, nginx, config, dancer

I have some sensitive information (my database username/password and cookie encryption key) in my config file for my Dancer application that I would rather not be shown as plain text in case someone does gain access to it.  What's the best way to encrypt the file so it's not just text?  Or is there a more secure approach that makes more sense than encryption (like restricting file permissions)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "What's the best way" type of questions are likely to be flagged and closed as being opinion based. Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Encrypting the config file is useless because your Dancer app will need the encryption key to access the database; if your app is compromised, an attacker would have access to the key, so it's hardly different from not encrypting at all.

Comment: A stronger security model is to have three separate servers: one for your webserver, one for your application, and one for your database. That way if your webserver is compromised the attacker doesn't have access to the database. I'm not sure whether Dancer could be set up to work in such an architecture, though (nor if it would even make sense for a micro-framework).

Comment: Ditto on encrypting the config file. If you're trying to protect username/password info in a production environment, one way common way to do it is to set these as environment variables at the OS level. This keeps your production credentials out of your GIT repository.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because you can't encrypt the config, as in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856318/how-to-encrypt-config-file-in-a-perl-dancer-application#comment40458268_25856318) above says @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, but sometmes is good to hide passwords (e.g. hide the passowrds form some co-workers who doesn't knows perl - but has access to config files)

I'm using an combination of

- security by obscurity
- and fooling

In my config files are passwords in encrypted form, and *looks like* as instructions for configuration. If someone grabs/reads only the config file - get nothing usable.

Usually I'm using something like the next:

```
db.password: enter some safe password here such De4w.Quafy3yq
```

and in the code i exracting the "De4w.Quafy3yq" part and using `rot13` or `crypt` etc... get the real passwd: "Qr4j.Dhnsl3ld". Or using the mh5 hash of a string as a password, or similar - simple algorithms.

It is simple, and effective against non-programmers - of course, isn't helps when someone knows perl and grabs the code too.

### EDIT

Because seems (downvotes) than here are still some people who didn't understand what this mean, ***THIS ISN'T ANY REAL SECURITY***. It is an nice (funny) method (of course unsecure - read again, it isn't mean any real security) how to hide the password form coworkers, who didn't knows perl. **DON'T USE IT** for any real password protection. OMG...

Comment: If you're just hiding credentials from users who already have access to the server, another option (if your database systems supports it) would be to connect using credentials stored in a file ([option files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html) with MySQL, [`.pgpass`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-pgpass.html) with Postgres, etc.), which you can set restrictive permissions on. This way even if other users have access to the Dancer config file, they wouldn't have access to the connection credentials.

Comment: I actually don't share the server with people that I'd be worried about seeing the password (it's my own VPS), I was thinking more along the lines of the rare case where someone does happen to hack into or gain access to the server.

Comment: @Buuntu Security is an brittle thing - and I don't like recommending, because each server has its own specifics. Maybe one thing - all (my own) servers runs on BSD in separate jails, the DB server is alone in one jail too. To db-server is allowed to connect only from the jails, passwords are cleartext... But as i told - each app, each server has its own needs and I haven't enough courage to recommending anything... ;)